# How to upgrade PostgreSQL on EC2?

Tags: amazon-ec2, postgresql

I have an Amazon EC2 instance running PostgreSQL 9.1. I am pointing to the RedHat repo for PostgreSQL. Now that 9.2 is out, how do I upgrade? This is new to me.

Comment: You'd wait until the package is available from the repo, then do `yum update`.

Comment: Ah. I wasn't sure if minor releases would show. Thanks @ceejayoz

Comment: @ceejayoz Actually, the Amazon packaging for PostgreSQL is dangerously wrong, and can result in an unusable DB if you just update. It updates from 9.1 to 9.2 without `pg_upgrade` or a dump and reload. See http://people.planetpostgresql.org/andrew/index.php?/archives/297-Amazons-serious-PostgreSQL-packaging-blunder.html and Amazon's "answer" here: http://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-ami/faqs/#postgresql9

Answer (score 1):

1. You can use the PGDG repo RPMs available [here](http://yum.postgresql.org/repopackages.php) (just `wget`
   and `rpm -i`). Then, you should probably use `pg_dump[all]` to
   snapshot your databases/clusters, verify the dumps, uninstall the
   old version of Postgres, and install the new version. Restore the
   dumps, and you're good to go.
2. For a slightly faster alternative (which I haven't used), you could
   use the upgrade utilities that I hear are available via the
   `postgresql-contrib` packages to perform the above process in an
   automated/managed fashion.
3. A third alternative, if downtime is absolutely unacceptable during
   an upgrade dump/restore, is to start a second instance of Postgres
   (the new version), and replicate your data from the old to the new
   using [Slony](http://slony.info/) or similar. That will probably not be easy to set
   up, however. I'd suggest just scheduling some maintenance, and using
   option 1 or 2.

Comment: `pg_upgrade` is probably the tool you're talking about. If so, it works completely differently to (1), doing an in-place upgrade. See http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/pgupgrade.html

Answer (score 0):

On the Amazon Linux EC2, you can install the newer version of postgres via

```
sudo amazon-linux-extras install postgresql12
```

To list the Amazon Linux add-on services use the command:

```
amazon-linux-extras list
```

Reference: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/amazon-linux-ami-basics.html#extras-library