# Upgrading PostgreSQL on EC2 with minimum impact to existing configuration

Tags: amazon-ec2, postgresql, yum, package-management, database-administration

I have PostgreSQL 9.2 installed on an EC2 instance, with `yum install`. I now need to upgrade to PostgreSQL 9.4. I've noticed that `yum list` lists 9.2, 9.3 and 9.4 as completely separate packages, so I can't just upgrade using yum upgrade functionality.

I have a database that needs to survive the updgrade. Furthermore, I have some configuration set up in `/var/lib/pgsql9/data` (server certificate/key in `.crt`/`.key` files, changes to `pg_hba.conf`, changes to `postgresql.conf`) that should also survive.

I saw [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/429624/how-to-upgrade-postgresql-on-ec2) but the information there is not relevant to the yum package scenario (and seems outdated), and furthermore does not specifically address the config concerns.

What is the proper/recommended way to accomplish the upgrade while keeping my config settings and ensuring the database will be operational after the upgrade?

Answer (score 4):

I found a way to do this, but I'm not sure if it's the proper/recommended way. My steps are below:

**1. Save the existing configuration**

Run `sudo vim /var/lib/pgsql9/data/postgresql.conf` and `sudo vim /var/lib/pgsql9/data/pg_hba.conf` and copy all uncommented settings somewhere. You'll later have to manually set them in the new PostgreSQL version.

**2. Install the new PostgreSQL version**

Use `yum list` to find the correct package names and install them. In my case I needed to `sudo yum install postgresql94.x86_64` and `sudo yum install postgresql94-server.x86_64`

Run `postgres --version`, `pg_dumpall --version` and `psql --version` to ensure that the version has been updated to the new one.

**3. Save existing data and shut down the database**

Stop any processes that may change the database (e.g. your web app). Run `sudo pg_dumpall >db.out`, followed by `sudo service postgresql stop` right after that to stop the server and prevent further data changes. Examine the resulting data dump with `vim db.out` - it should have all your DB schema and data in plain SQL format. You may wish to back up this file before proceeding.

**4. Save the old database directory**

`sudo mv /var/lib/pgsql9 /var/lib/pgsql9.old`

**5. Create a new database directory for the new PostgreSQL version**

`sudo mkdir /var/lib/pgsql9`

`sudo chown postgres /var/lib/pgsql9`

`sudo su postgres`

In the `sudo su` prompt:
`initdb -D /var/lib/pgsql9/data`

Then press `Ctrl-D`

**6. Copy certificates to the new database directory**

If you are using certificates, copy them to the new directory and give them the proper ownership, e.g:

`sudo cp /var/lib/pgsql9.old/data/server.key /var/lib/pgsql9/data`

`sudo cp /var/lib/pgsql9.old/data/server.crt /var/lib/pgsql9/data`

`sudo chown postgres /var/lib/pgsql9/data/server.crt`

`sudo chown postgres /var/lib/pgsql9/data/server.key`

**7. Configure the new database**

Use `sudo vim /var/lib/pgsql9/data/postgresql.conf` and `sudo vim /var/lib/pgsql9/data/pg_hba.conf` to configure the database according to the settings you saved back in step 1.

**8. Fix the postgresql service to point to the new version**

Run `ls -ila /etc/rc.d/init.d` - notice how you have a script for every version (`postgresql92`, `postgresql94`), but `postgresql` itself is linked to the old version. Fix this by running `sudo ln -sf /etc/rc.d/init.d/postgresql94 /etc/rc.d/init.d/postgresql` and run the `ls` command again to verify the link is correct.

**9. Run the service**

Run `sudo service postgresql start`. If the service fails to start, chances are it's either a permissions error (you forgot a `chown` step above) or a configuration syntax error. You can look at logs (`/var/lib/pgsql94/pgstartup.log` and the files in `/var/lib/pgsql9/data/pg_log`) to look for the error. If the service has started correctly, you can run `sudo su postgres`, then `psql` to verify your database is running (use `\q` to quit and press Ctrl-D to get out of `sudo su`).

**10. Restore your old data**

`sudo cp db.out /var/lib/pgsql9/data`

`sudo chown postgres /var/lib/pgsql9/data/db.out`

`sudo su postgres`

And in that prompt:

`psql -d postgres -f /var/lib/pgsql9/data/db.out`

You should see a bunch of database commands scroll by. At that point your database is upgraded and running. You can verify by running `psql`. Use `\list` command to see a list of databases, `\connect (database_name)` to connect to your database, `\dt` to see a list of tables once connected, or run semicolon-terminated SQL commands. Type `\q` to quit.

Once done verifying, press `Ctrl-D` to exit `sudo su`.

**11. Clean up**

At this point, once you're sure everything is working, you may remove `/var/lib/pgsql9.old`, `/var/lib/pgsql9/db.out`, `db.out` and any other backups.